# UITableViewCell not covering full frame of UITableView in a ContainerView of tvOS

Tags: swift, uitableview, tvos, uicontainerview

I have a viewController, in first 75% I am showing an Imageview and in another 25% I have placed a containerView. A containerView have a UITableView with a UITableViewCell. The UITableViewCell(blue background) in a tableview(red background) is not occupying the full width of tableview.
Please refer to the attached screenshot.

Also How can we remove spacing between the cells(like iOS UITableView)?

[image: Screenshot showing the 75% covering ImageView, another 25% with ContainView having UItableView]

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example. This will help others to fix your approach instead of coming up with a solution from scratch. [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: You can get above by just adding UITableView to UIVIewController

Comment: I think It may be due to 
https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/tvos/visual-design/layout/